# How do I pull the data from the row I want to the row I want in the column of a table in the database in php?

Tags: php

For example, account1 in the email column of the experiment table of the account sales database
account2
account3
account4
I entered an account on each line in the form of account5 and I want to pull data from line 0 to line 3. How can I do that?

```
`<?php
include("baglanti.php");

$start_row = 0; // Başlangıç satırı
$row_count = 3; // Çekilecek satır sayısı

$sql = "SELECT eposta FROM deneme LIMIT $start_row, $row_count";

$result = $baglan->query($sql);

if ($result->rowCount() > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "E-posta: " . $row["eposta"] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "Sonuç bulunamadı.";
}

// Veritabanı bağlantısını kapat
$baglan = null;
?>`
```

I tried this code and it doesn't pull data from row 0 to row 3, it pulls all data of email column.